# Can't use Advanced User Interactions in Webdriverjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver

I am trying to use [webdriverjs](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) to click on a flash animation.

I tried using the Advanced User interactions, but I can't seem to click where I want.
Not even when I try to click a normal web element, such as a button.

Optimally, I would like to do something like the following:

```
element = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.Id("elementID"));

driver.actions()
.mouseMove(element)
.mouseClick()
.perform();
```

-or-

```
driver.actions()
.click(element)
.perform();
```

However, the feedback I get from the standalone server is always in the form of [someaction: nothing].

I tried enabling firefox native events in browser capabilities via 'nativeEvents': true, but it didn't help.

I can use webdriverjs to click on elements on a page normally otherwise. (except for flash)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot interact with Flash objects.

If you want to do this you would need to modify the source code of the flash object to provide some test hooks that JavaScript could access and then use something like:

- https://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/
- https://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/